# C++ map container erase() segmentation fault

Tags: c++, stdmap

I use this code to remove elements from map container that equal to some int.

```
for(auto x:m){
  if((x.second)==element)m.erase(x.first);
}
```

As result Segmentation fault. I also tried this:

```
for(map<int,int>::iterator i=m.begin();i!=m.end();i++){
  if((i->second)==element)m.erase(i);
}
```

Same result. If you put i++ into if/else program will freeze/loop or something. How can I fix this?

Comment: Step 0: show us a [mcve]. Not just code snippets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`erase()` invalidates the iterator being used by the `for` loop. Fortunately, `erase()` itself returns an iterator to the next entry, so the correct loop would look like this instead:

```
for (map<int,int>::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); )
{
    if (i->second == element)
        i = m.erase(i);
    else
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: Note in particular the absence of `++i` on the first line. Very important.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @john's answer, if your C++ Standard Library implementation supports it, you can invoke the [`std::erase_if(map, condition)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if) helper:

```
std::erase_if(m, [](const auto& item) {
    auto const& [key, value] = item;
    // Write your erasing condition here, e.g.:
    // return value == element;
});
```

Comment: It's a shame you can't put the structured binding in the parameter list. Kind of.

Comment: Structured bindings is great, but here, I would simply prefer `return item.second == element;`. It's simply shorter.

Comment: @DanielLangr: `key` and `value` (or even more context-specific names) are in general more readable than `first` and `second`.

Comment: I like it how it is in the answer. It is free to the computer, and well worth the extra line in terms of cognitive load. `.first` and `.second` are just horrible.